# Can a Group Own a Record?

Tags: sharing, ownership

Experience with the platform tells me the answer is "no".

But I notice that [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood.meta/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood/uth_arch.htm) says that a "group" can "own" a record.

> Salesforce stores access grants in three types of tables.
>
> Object Record Tables Tables that store the records of a specific
> object, and indicate which user, group, or queue owns each record.
>
> ...

OK. So based on my understanding of this table, "own" means the "OwnerID" column in the appropriate sObject Record Table would contain the ID of the owning entity. A User or a Queue can own a record in this way. But a "group"? What is meant by this? Public Groups cannot "own" a record in this way. A Role cannot "own" a record in this way.

I am left wondering... what is meant by "own" and "group" in the Documentation referenced above?

Comment: also - before someone just links me some generic documentation... I do understand how the Object Share and Group Maintenance Tables work, I do understand how records are SHARED with groups (Public Groups and Role Groups). I also know that RECORD ACCESS is not OWNERSHIP. So I'm basically pointing out that a literal reading of the Documentation above doesn't line up with what I know about the platform.

Comment: A Queue is a Group. Queues can own leads, case and custom objects. `Owner` on Lead or Case is a polymorphic field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of documentation on the platform. Some of it is bound to have imprecise or confusing wording (or in some occasions, just flat out wrong wording). I think this is just one of those situations. Perhaps general group ownership of records was a feature on the roadmap at some point, but it'd be hard to confirm or deny that.

Generally speaking, I believe your experience is correct. Groups cannot own SObject records. The two exceptions to that which I know of are `Task` and `Case`. In both of those cases though, only groups of type "Queue" can own the record. There are likely more (documentation suggests `Lead` and any custom object too).

Yep, there isn't a "Queue" SObject (though there is `QueueSObject`, which is something else). A queue is just a `Group` record where the `Type` field is "Queue". Nice way to muddy the waters even more.

### Summary

- The record "owner" is the entity pointed to by the `OwnerId` field (where available, objects on the detail side of a master-detail relationship are owned by the entity that owns the master record)
- Record ownership is not equal to record access, *but it does form the basis of record access*
- A Queue is a subtype of the `Group` SObject
- So, while saying a "Group" can own a record is technically correct, that'd be a misleading statement
- Queues can own records of some (but not all) SObjects