# Assign Task to public group apex

Tags: apex, public-group

Salesforce allows us to create task with ownerId as single user/to a queue through apex. I would like to know if it's possible to create a task with ownerId as publicGroup ID. I know that we can query the group members and create a task for each user from that group.

Below is the sample code that I tried and which have me error as,

```
Group g = [SELECT Name
                FROM Group
                WHERE Name = 'Test Group' LIMIT 1];
ID qID = g.ID;
List<Task> tList = new List<Task>();
Task t = new Task();
t.OwnerId = qID;
tList.add(t);
insert tList;
```

Error:

[image]

Just looking for a confirmation on this part.

Comment: Hi KSL, You need to query the public group id in the query

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi, It's not required to query the Id field separately in SOQL

Comment: As per my investigation public groups will not own the record. Please refer this [link] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319229/can-a-group-own-a-record)

Comment: Yes @TSmith, It is enabled

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi, Thanks for the link.

Comment: Does your Group have Group Members? The ideal approach here is to assign the Task OwnerId to the `UserOrGroupId` from the `GroupMember` of that Public Group.

Comment: @TSmith, The group has GroupMembers. I agree with you on assigning separate task to each GroupMember. My question is about is there any possibility to directly assign to Group. I think the other reply in the comments has provided the info to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Queues and Users may own records. Thus, you cannot use a Public Group directly to assign a task to multiple users. It is trivial to copy a Public Group to a Queue, however, since they share the same base object, the Group object.